# Creating an array within an object within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Using Javascript, how do I create an array within an object that's within an object, so that my value is stored at: main[1].type[1][0]

I have tried and my code which does not work is as follows:

```js
let main = []

main[1] = {type: {1:['Value1', 'Value2']}, {2:['Value3', 'Value4']}};

console.log(main[1].type[0][1]);
```

I expect `main[1].type[1][0]` to be `'Value1'` but it is `undefined`

Comment: Your `type` property value cannot be two comma separated Objects. It can be an Array of Objects, though. Of course, we all have to ask, why use Object properties as numbers, as well? They will be converted to Strings, so you still won't be able to rely on proper order. Use actual Array indexes to preserve order.

Comment: Let's clarify terminology — your question says _"an array within an object within an object"_, but your `main = []` is an Array, so that changes it to _"an array within and object within an **array**_". Your `main[1]` (array) _does_ contain an object; that object has just _one_ member named `type`. The value of _type_ is an object with two keys — those keys are `1` and `2`, making it sort-of look like an array, but _it's not_. 1 and 2 each contain an array (of Strings) — so what you actually have (from Paulpro's answer) is _an array within an object within an object within an array_.

Comment: @StephenP This is true, but the OP didn't specify the declaration of `main` (that was edited in by someone else), so we don't know whether `main` is an array or a regular object for the OP. Either way, `['Value1', 'Value2']` is "an array within an object within an object [within main]"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not getting `undefined`. You have a syntax error. A comma should either be separating array values, or separating object entries. You have a comma here, in an object, so it is expected to have a key after it, not a `{`

```
main[1] = {type: {1:['Value1', 'Value2']}, {2:['Value3', 'Value4']}};
                                         |
                                         |
                           Remove the } and { around this comma
```

Remove the `}` and `{` around the comma so that `{1:['Value1', 'Value2'], 2:['Value3', 'Value4']}` becomes a single object with two keys:

```js
const main = [];

main[1] = {type: {1:['Value1', 'Value2'], 2:['Value3', 'Value4']}};

console.log( main[1].type[1][0] );
```

Answer (score 1):

First your declaration is wrong and will not works.

`{type: {}, {}}` isn't a valid JSON and you must wrap it into `[]` to create array of object `{type: [{}, {}]}`.

Also by adding a level you will have to ask for: `main[1].type[0][1][0]` to get the complet path to `Value1`

```js
let main = []
main[1] = {type: [{1:['Value1', 'Value2']}, {2:['Value3', 'Value4']}]};

console.log(main[1].type[0][1][0])
```

Comment: JSON is unrelated, and your object is not valid JSON either. keys must be strings in JSON, and all strings (keys and values) must use double quotes as delimiters.

Comment: Way wanted to say JS boject and not JSON, but in all cases you're answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you can not create an object with a numbered object inside it you have to use the array notation `var variableName = [/*variable values here separated by commas*/]`

This will fix your problem:

```
let main = []

main[1] = {
  type: [
    ['Value1', 'Value2'], 
    ['Value3', 'Value4']
  ]
};

console.log(main[1].type[0][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down your issue, an object must be "zero or more pairs of property names and associated values of an object." The second value in the question's code does not have a key, causing an uncaught `SyntaxError`.

Here's an object literal that returns your desired result:

```
const main = {
  1: {
    type: { 1: ['Value1', 'Value2'] },
    otherType: { 2: ['Value3', 'Value4'] },
  },
};
```

```
main[1].type[1][0] 
=> "Value1"
```

[Object initializer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use sparse arrays :

```js
let main = [, { type: [, ['Value1', 'Value2'], ['Value3', 'Value4'] ] } ];

console.log(main[1].type[1][0]);
```